# Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Route could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to do something very simple.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Route::view('/welcome', 'welcome');
});
```

I just want to it to load the `welcome` view and change the URI to `/welcome`. However, as you can see it keeps throwing the error `Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Route could not be converted to string`.

I haven't touched Laravel in a minute and am kind of doing a refresher and tried to set up a simple site. I may be missing something totally obvious but I have no idea what it could be.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the docs for a refresher? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mean like

```
Route::redirect('/', '/welcome', 301);
Route::view('/welcome', 'welcome');
```

or

```
//one view like resources/views/welcome.blade.php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

But in fact we usually use .htaccess redirect request, because you must load all requires before do anything in framework.

Comment: Wow, excuse my ignorance. It's 6 AM and I haven't slept yet. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: A hahaha, no problem, I'm from China.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
 Route::view('/','welcome');
```

Or use

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});
```

I guess you are mixing two different syntax.

[http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-5-5-new-feature-route-view-and-route-redirect-method-with-example]